# Angular 4 Form Reset Submits to Server

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-forms, forms

I have the following HTML form:

```
<form class="row" name="powerPlantSearchForm" (ngSubmit)="f.valid && searchPowerPlants()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="powerPlantName">PowerPlant Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control-small" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !powerPlantName.valid }" name="powerPlantName" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantName" #powerPlantName="ngModel" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="powerPlantType">PowerPlant Type</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantType" name="powerPlantType">
              <option value="" disabled>--Select Type--</option>
              <option [ngValue]="powerPlantType" *ngFor="let powerPlantType of powerPlantTypes">
                {{ powerPlantType }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="organizationName">Organization Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control-small" name="powerPlantOrganization" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantOrg" #organizationName="ngModel" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="powerPlantStatus">PowerPlant Active Status</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantStatus" name="powerPlantStatus">
              <option value="" disabled>--Select Status--</option>
              <option [ngValue]="powerPlantStatus" *ngFor="let powerPlantStatus of powerPlantStatuses">
                {{ powerPlantStatus }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-4">
            <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            <img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="f.reset()">Reset</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

This is my component:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  // Represents the PowerPlantTypes
  powerPlantTypes = ['RampUpType', 'OnOffType'];
  // Represents the status of a PowerPlant
  powerPlantStatuses = ['Active & Disabled', 'Active', 'Disabled'];
  // Represents the search form
  model: any = {};
  // currentUser: User;
  // represents the list of PowerPlant data
  powerPlants: PowerPlant[];
  users: User[] = [];

  constructor(private powerPlantService: PowerPlantService) {
    // this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    // Set the initial values for the drop down fields in the UI
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.model.powerPlantType = '';
    this.model.powerPlantStatus = '';
  }

  selectName() {
    alert(this.model.powerPlantType);
  }

  searchPowerPlants(): void {
    const powerPlantSearchParams = new PowerPlantSearchParams(
      this.model.powerPlantType,
      this.model.powerPlantOrg,
      this.model.powerPlantName,
      this.model.page,
      this.model.powerPlantStatus);

    this.powerPlantService.searchPowerPlants(powerPlantSearchParams).subscribe(result => {
      this.powerPlants = <PowerPlant[]> result;
    });
  }

  allPowerPlants(onlyActive: boolean = false, page: number = 1): void {
    this.powerPlantService.allPowerPlants(onlyActive, page).subscribe(result => {
      this.powerPlants = <PowerPlant[]> result;
    });
  }
}
```

When I click the reset button in my html page, the method searchPowerPlants() is getting called. How could I avoid this?

EDIT: After using type="reset", it does not submit anymore to the server, but the dropdown shows some other value instead of the default value. It can be seen from the screenshot below that the dropdown now shows RampUpType as the PowerPlantType after hitting the Reset button, but rather I would have wanted it show the --Select Type--

[image]

Comment: Try to put type="reset' on the that button?

Comment: Yes, any button that does **not** have `type="button"` or `type="reset"` will trigger a form submit when `ngSubmit()` is present on the `<form>` tag

Comment: You can see more about type attribute in button element [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I got another strange error! Please have a look at my edited post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your button put type="button" and remove `f.reset()`. Instead:

```
    <button type="button" (click)="reset()" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
```

and

```
  reset(){
    this.model.powerPlantType = '';
    this.model.powerPlantStatus = '';

  }
```

You can also call reset() from ngOnInit().
But don't forget to add resetting values for other inputs too.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zx3uwx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Cool! That is what I did! Thanks!

Comment: I additionally had to remove the disabled in the <option value="" disabled>

Comment: I am guessing it resolves the previous question also?

Comment: Yes! Definitely!

Comment: The key here was to remove the disabled in the option tag! I accepted your answer and gave you an up vote. Can you also please up vote my question!

Comment: Let me give that a try!

Comment: Glad to help :)